# How can I convert a Java Iterable to a Scala Iterable?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

Is there an easy way to convert a

```
java.lang.Iterable[_]
```

to a

```
Scala.Iterable[_]
```

?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In Scala 2.8 this became much much easier, and there are two ways to achieve it.  One that's sort of explicit (although it *uses* implicits):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val myJavaIterable = someExpr()

val myScalaIterable = myJavaIterable.asScala
```

*EDIT:* Since I wrote this, the Scala community has arrived at a broad consensus that `JavaConverters` is good, and `JavaConversions` is bad, because of the potential for spooky-action-at-a-distance.  So don't use `JavaConversions` at all!

---

<strike>And one that's more like an implicit implicit: :)</strike>

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val myJavaIterable = someExpr()

for (magicValue <- myJavaIterable) yield doStuffWith(magicValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer and stating the good practice :)

Answer (score 11):

Yes use **implicit** conversions:

```
import java.lang.{Iterable => JavaItb}
import java.util.{Iterator => JavaItr}

implicit def jitb2sitb[T](jit: JavaItb[T]): Iterable[T] = new SJIterable(jit);
implicit def jitr2sitr[A](jit: JavaItr[A]): Iterator[A] = new SJIterator(jit)
```

Which can then be easily implemented:

```
class SJIterable[T](private val jitb: JavaItr[T]) extends Iterable[T] {
  def elements(): Iterator[T] = jitb.iterator()
}

class SJIterator[T](private val jit: JavaItr[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
  def hasNext: Boolean = jit hasNext

  def next: T = jit next
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was something like this in the standard Scala libs, but as you've shown, it's not too hard to roll your own.

Comment: It's ridiculous thinking how much code this would have been the other way around!

Comment: This will be in the standard library starting with Scala 2.8.

Answer (score 8):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, package [`scala.jdk.CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/javaapi/CollectionConverters$.html) replaces deprecated packages `scala.collection.JavaConverters/JavaConversions`:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

// val javaIterable: java.lang.Iterable[Int] = Iterable(1, 2, 3).asJava
javaIterable.asScala
// Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```