# scala implicit or explicit conversion from iterator to iterable

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Does Scala provide a built-in class, utility, syntax, or other mechanism for converting (by wrapping) an Iterator with an Iterable?

For example, I have an Iterator[Foo] and I need an Iterable[Foo], so currently I am:

```
 val foo1: Iterator[Foo] = ....
 val foo2: Iterable[Foo] = new Iterable[Foo] {
   def elements = foo1
 }
```

This seems ugly and unnecessary. What's a better way?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072784/how-can-i-convert-a-java-iterable-to-a-scala-iterable

Comment: @wheaties this is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Iterator` has a `toIterable` method in Scala 2.8.0, but not in 2.7.7 or earlier. It's not implicit, but you could define your own implicit conversion if you need one.

Answer (score 8):

You should be **very careful** about *ever implicitly* converting an `Iterator` into an `Iterable` (I normally use `Iterator.toList`  - explicitly). The reason for this is that, by passing the result into a method (or function) which expects an `Iterable`, you lose control of it to the extent that *your program might be broken*. Here's one example:

```
def printTwice(itr : Iterable[String]) : Unit = {
    itr.foreach(println(_))
    itr.foreach(println(_))
}
```

If an `Iterator` were somehow implicitly convertible into an `Iterable`, what will the following would print?

```
printTwice(Iterator.single("Hello"))
```

It will (of course) only print *Hello* once. Very recently, the `trait` `TraversableOnce` has been added to the collections library, which unifies `Iterator` and `Iterable`. To my mind, this is arguably a mistake.

My personal preference is to use `Iterator` explicitly wherever possible and then use `List`, `Set` or `IndexedSeq` directly. I have found that I can rarely write a method which is genuinely agnostic of the type it is passed. One example:

```
def foo(trades: Iterable[Trade]) {
  log.info("Processing %d trades", trades.toList.length) //hmmm, converted to a List

  val shorts = trades.filter(_.side.isSellShort)
  log.info("Found %d sell-short", shorts.toList.length) //hmmm, converted to a List again

  //etc
```

Comment: I -1'd you because your statement "It will (of course) only print Hello once" is false.  Scala's `toIterable` wraps the Iterator in a Stream, which ensures that you get the proper multiple iteration semantics.  This makes much of your answer incorrect.