# In java code, getting a scala.Iterable from a java.util.List

Tags: java, scala

I knew this '[How can I convert a Java Iterable to a Scala Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072784/how-can-i-convert-a-java-iterable-to-a-scala-iterable)'

But I am working on **java 1.4.2** code with a scala API.

How can I get a `scala.Iterable` from a `java.util.List`?

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Is that running on a 1.5 or 1.6 JVM, with 1.4 source code, or is it full 1.4? Because Scala 2.8, afaik, does not support Java 1.4.

Comment: It is running with scala 2.7.4 on java 1.4 with a JVM 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need is in `scala.lang.JavaConversions`

```
import java.util.{List => JList, ArrayList}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val jul1: JList[String] = new ArrayList[String]; jul1.add("Boo!")

val sb1 = jul1.toBuffer
val ss1 = jul1.toSeq // Same result as toBuffer
```

This produces a *mutable* collection in sml1 (a `Buffer`). If you want an immutable collection (`List`, e.g.) convert that mutable collection:

```
val sl1 = jul1.toList
```

*Edit:* Hmm... Java *1.4.2*? That's pre-generics? (I lose track of such ancient history...) This probably won't work, then... You'll probably need to work with existential types.

Comment: You know in enterprise we have some pre-19700101 code ^^ No elegant method therefore, just loop on java Collection and manual adding in a scala Collection...

Comment: You said you wanted a `scala.Iterable`. I assumed you were writing Scala code that needed to consume a Java collection.

Comment: in fact, I have a scala method to call in my java code (from a scala API a colleague has written) which take for parameters a scala.Iterable. But at this step of my source code, I have a java.util.List in version 1.4.2 (that does not implement java.util.Iterable since it does not exist in 1.4.2). And I would like to call the scala method fed by a scala.Iterable with my "not 1.5 Iterable" java.util.List...

Comment: Actually, I don't think Scala is compatible with Java 1.4.