# Should I use collectionAsScalaIterable({java collection}) or Seq({java collection}).flatten?

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

We're starting to use Scala Test to test our Java application, and I want to test the contents of a Java Collection. We came up with 2 possibilities:

```
JavaConversions.collectionAsScalaIterable(getJavaCollection()) must contain(allOf(item1, item2).inOrder)
```

or

```
Seq(getJavaCollection()).flatten mustEqual Seq(item1, item2)
```

Being a beginner to Scala, I'm wondering which way would be better (or is there a better way)?

Answer (score 2):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val col = getJavaCollection().asScala //a scala mutable Buffer
col mustEqual Seq(item1, item2)
```

You can use `col` as a `Seq` and perform necessary calculations.

Sometimes it is best to google :)

1. [How can I convert a Java Iterable to a Scala Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072784/how-can-i-convert-a-java-iterable-to-a-scala-iterable?rq=1)
2. [How to convert a java.util.List to a Scala list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162090/how-to-convert-java-util-list-to-scala-list?rq=1)
3. [Iterating over Java collections in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495741/iterating-over-java-collections-in-scala?rq=1)
4. [Converting a Java collection into a Scala collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674713/converting-a-java-collection-into-a-scala-collection)

Comment: If I use mustEqual as in your answer, I get `Wrappers(item1, item2) is not equal to List(item1, item2)`. However, I can do `getJavaCollection().asScala must contain(allOf(item1, item2).inOrder)` and it passes. Thanks for the pointer to JavaConverters.